# How to redirect subdomain to subdomain?

Tags: magento2, redirect, nginx, htaccess

I have a question for config url rewrite on **.htaccess** file.
On my store have two language is **English** and **German**.
I setup English with domain **main.cocal** and German is **de.main.local**.
so for now I want new setup for **ch-de.main.local** will be redirect to **de.main.local**. How I do that?
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to just use an nginx temporary redirect instead.

```
server {
    . . .
    server_name ch-de.main.local;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://de.main.local/$1 redirect;
    . . .
}

server {
    . . .
    server_name de.main.local;
    . . .
}
```

I wouldnt bother with htaccess if you have nginx.

Comment: many thanks @shapeshifter